# Tool for database comparison

Tags: windows, database

I am looking for a tool that allows me to compare two SQL Server databases, see the differences, and move the changes from one database to another. In simpler terms, I want a tool exactly like the Schema Compare tool from Visual Studio, but without forcing me to have the Premium or Ultimate edition of VS.

Here are the requirements:

- Free
- Compatible with SQL Server 2008 or later databases
- Must compare both structure and data
- For Windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SchemaCrawler](http://www.SchemaCrawler.com) is a free and open-source command-line tool that produces text (text, JSON, CSV, HTML) output that is designed to be diff-ed, using standard diff tools. It can compare both structure and data, and will work on Windows. However, it will not automatically move changes from one database to another.

Sualeh Fatehi, SchemaCrawler

Answer (score 1):

> [Open DBDiff](https://opendbiff.codeplex.com/) is an open source
>   database schema comparison tool for SQL Server 2005/2008.
>
> It reports differences between two database schemas and provides a
>   synchronization script to upgrade a database from one to the other.

Answer (score 0):

TiCodeX SQL Schema Compare (https://www.ticodex.com) is a database schema comparison tools.
It runs on windows, linux and mac and can compare Microsoft SQL Server, MySQL and Postgresql databases.
And it's multi language.